# MySQL using LIKE and AND not getting correct results

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Hopefully a simple question to people with better brains than me - I am having trouble with my MySQL syntax when Selecting rows from a table.

```
$query="SELECT auth, first_name, last_name FROM main_user
    WHERE (auth='1' OR auth='2'
      AND CONCAT(first_name,' ',last_name) LIKE '%".$client_name."%')
    LIMIT 10";
```

I am basically wanting to retrieve the client name based on the user input whos 'auth' is set to either 1 or 2.

My current results seem to be bringing back results where only 'auth' values are matching.

Answer (score 2):

```
auth='1' OR auth='2' AND CONCAT(first_name,' ',last_name) LIKE '%".$client_name."%'
```

This is equivalent to

```
(auth='1') 
OR (
       auth='2' 
   AND CONCAT(first_name,' ',last_name) LIKE '%".$client_name."%'
   )
```

You should instead write it as

```
(
    auth='1' 
OR  auth='2'
)  
AND CONCAT(first_name,' ',last_name) LIKE '%".$client_name."%'
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to put these `OR` in brackets like so:

```
SELECT 
  auth, 
  first_name, 
  last_name 
FROM main_user
WHERE (auth = '1' OR auth = '2')
  AND CONCAT(first_name,' ',last_name) LIKE '%".$client_name."%')
LIMIT 10;
```

Answer (score 1):

You got the `()` wrong. Try

```
SELECT auth, first_name, last_name
FROM main_user
WHERE (auth = '1' OR auth = '2')
AND CONCAT(first_name,' ',last_name) LIKE '%".$client_name."%'
LIMIT 10
```

or simpler

```
SELECT auth, first_name, last_name
FROM main_user
WHERE auth in ('1','2')
AND CONCAT(first_name,' ',last_name) LIKE '%".$client_name."%'
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: @MichelFeldheim Hard to say exactly without your (exmaple) data.
`(a OR b AND c)`
means
`( a or ( b AND c )`
You need
`( ( a OR b ) AND c )`

Comment: Not mine, just walked by and commented :)

Answer (score 1):

Please try executing the below mentioned sql select query.

I have replaced OR operator with IN in below sql query

```
 $query="SELECT auth, first_name, last_name FROM main_user
WHERE auth in ('1','2')
  AND CONCAT(first_name,' ',last_name) LIKE '%".$client_name."%')
LIMIT 10";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the two OR clauses in parens:

```
WHERE ( ( auth='1' OR auth='2' )
     AND ...
```